# Sprite animation stuck on first frame?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, game-development

Working with Phaser 3, I've preloaded a spritesheet and created a few animations...

```
import {Scene} from 'phaser';

class BootScene extends Scene {
  constructor() {
    super("scene-boot");
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.spritesheet('px-hero', 'assets/sprites/px-hero.png', {
      frameWidth: 16,
      frameHeight: 16
    });
    // ...
  }

  create() {
    // ...
    this.anims.create({
      key: 'px-hero-idle',
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('px-hero', {
        start: 0,
        end: 2
      }),
      frameRate: 10,
      repeat: -1
    });

    this.anims.create({
      key: 'px-hero-run',
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('px-hero', {
        start: 3,
        end: 6
      }),
      frameRate: 10,
      repeat: -1
    });
    // ...
  }
}

export default BootScene;
```

Then inside my Sprite class (which is being instantiated in another scene that the BootScene links to), I'm trying to play the animations...

```
import {GameObjects} from 'phaser';
const {Sprite} = GameObjects;

class PxHero extends Sprite {
  constructor(config) {
    super(config.scene, config.x, config.y, "px-hero");

    // Add self to scene's physics
    config.scene.physics.world.enable(this);
    config.scene.add.existing(this);

    this.scene = config.scene;

    this.keys = this.scene.input.keyboard.addKeys('W,S,A,D');

    this.speed = 100;
    this.jumpHeight = 300;
  }

  preUpdate(time, delta) {
    const {W, S, A, D} = this.keys;
    const {speed, jumpHeight, body} = this;
    const touchingGround = body.blocked.down;

    if (A.isDown) {
      this.body.setVelocityX(-speed);
      this.setFlipX(true);
    }
    else if (D.isDown) {
      this.body.setVelocityX(speed);
      this.setFlipX(false);
    }
    else {
      this.body.setVelocityX(0);
    }

    if (W.isDown && touchingGround) {
      this.body.setVelocityY(-jumpHeight);
    }

    // Animations
    if (touchingGround) {
      if (body.velocity.x !== 0) {
        this.anims.play('px-hero-run', true); // here
      }
      else {
        this.anims.play('px-hero-idle', true); // and here
      }
    }
  }
}

export default PxHero;
```

But for some reason they just play the first frame of the animation then get stuck there.

Has anyone encountered this before? I haven't been able to find any solutions thus far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per frame animations are working based on `preUpdate` function, it's not the best idea to do something yours in that function without calling `super.preUpdate`. That's first, second in place of `preUpdate` try to use `update` function, and don't forget to call `super.update` in it.
And third, try to do what you want without using `preUpdate` and `update` functions. If you even need to use `update` function, you can do that with setting listener on scene to `update` (`Phaser.Scenes.Events.UPDATE`) event. Which will make your code more clear and understandable, and you'll never harm Phaser's main functionality by mistake.

What happens in your code is the following, on every frame rendering, your game checks and decides to run an animation from start, that's why you're seeing first frames only, just because when it tries to show you next frame you're telling him to start playing animation again )

```
export default class PxHero extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite{
  constructor(config) {
    super(config.scene, config.x, config.y, "px-hero");
    // Add self to scene's physics
    // ## you've `this` here too
    this.scene.add.existing(this);
    this.scene.physics.world.enable(this);
    this.prepare();
    this.setListeners();
  }

  prepare(){
    this.keys = this.scene.input.keyboard.addKeys('W,S,A,D');
    this.speed = 100;
    this.jumpHeight = 300;
  }

   setListeners(){
    this.scene.events.on(Phaser.Scenes.Events.UPDATE, this.handleMovement, this)
   }

  handleMovement() {
    const {W, S, A, D} = this.keys;
    const {speed, jumpHeight, body} = this;
    const touchingGround = body.blocked.down;
    switch(true){
     case A.isDown:
      this.body.setVelocityX(-speed);
      this.setFlipX(true);
     break;
     case D.isDown:
      this.body.setVelocityX(speed);
      this.setFlipX(false);
     break;
     case S.isDown:
      this.body.setVelocityX(0);
     break;
     case W.isDown && touchingGround:
      this.body.setVelocityY(-jumpHeight);
     break;
    }
    // Animations
    if (touchingGround) {
      if (body.velocity.x !== 0) {
        (!this.anims.isPlaying || this.anims.key !== 'px-her-run') && 
        this.anims.play('px-hero-run', true); // here
      }
      else {
        (!this.anims.isPlaying || this.anims.key !== 'px-her-idle') && 
        this.anims.play('px-hero-idle', true); // and here
      }
    }
  }
}
```